I am getting error in Your connection is not private Attackers might be trying to steal your information from localhost (for example, passwords)
I am getting this error in my .NET Core and Angular project even after installing the SSL certificate.

Your connection is not private Attackers might be trying to steal your
information from localhost (for example, passwords, messages, or
credit cards). Learn more about this warning

What was the issue? How to fix this?

looks like you are using https on localhost with an invalid or missing certificate. Try http instead.

http is not working , showing not secure https:

Check the certificate details in the browser. Does the hostname match?

Gagan.  I am assuming your issue is with IIS.  If this is true, you have to enable https and select the certificate.  Right-click the Default Web Site, select "Edit Bindings", add https and select your certificate.

but still it is not working

issue resolved  Import the Certificate:
Open Manage User Certificates:
Press Win + R and type certmgr.msc.
Navigate to Trusted Root Certification Authorities > Certificates.
Right-click, select Import, and follow the wizard to import the .pem or .pfx file.
